# Is there Simple way to use String.toLowerCase() for 9 kinds of languages?

Tags: java

I need to treat 9 kinds of language in a list below.

- Dutch
- English
- French
- German
- Italian
- Portuguese
- Russian
- Spanish
- Ukrainian

For words in these languages I need to use `tolowercase()`.
and I know I need to use `Locale(country, language)` as a parameter of the function.
Then, do I have to use specific locale for each language, or is there simpler way to do this?

Comment: and plus, Locale can treat all languages in list??

Comment: You could use a map to map your languages to locales...

Comment: I think it's important to know wheter you need the nine languages at the same time or just want depending on, for example, user settings.

Comment: A `Locale` is a tuple of `{language, script, country, variant, extensions}.` It's hard to see how you're not sure you need a specific one per language.

Answer (score 9):

You can construct a `Locale` from an ISO 639 language code:

```
Locale russian = new Locale("RU");
```

There are nice default locales for you to use, for example:

```
Locale english = Locale.ENGLISH;
Locale french = Locale.FRENCH;
Locale german = Locale.GERMAN;
Locale italian = Locale.ITALIAN;
```

Then just use `String#toLowerCase()` with the locale:

```
String lower = str.toLowerCase(someLocale);
```

Comment: exactly what I would have posted. +1 :-)